# What is the equivalent for useSSL = true in node js Sql pool connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, ssl-certificate

How can I set ssl as true in Nodejs sql pool connection ? (JDBC equivalent : `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Peoples?useSSL=true` )

Currently am passing below parameters to connect the DB in Node JS

```
mysql.createPool({
        host: dbHost,
        user: dbUser,
        password: dbPassword,
        database: dbName,
        port: dbPort,
        timezone: 'utc',
    });
```